# Combobox doesn't show display member and value member in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox

With `access` I don't have this problem but now that I'm using `SQL Serever` the `Combobox` doesn't work as it work before.

this is how I get `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` from `database` :

```
using (SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(StrCon))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter SqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(
               "Select HiveID, HiveNumber From tHives", SqlCon))
        {
            using (DataTable Dtable = new DataTable())
            {
                SqlDa.Fill(Dtable);

                HiveNumbercmb.DataSource = Dtable;
            }
        }
    }
```

And combobox property is set like this:

(in property window not by Code)

```
DisplayMember = HiveNumber
ValueMember = HiveID
```

but still instead of showing my HiveNumber it shows 3 Empty Item.

where is the problem?

Comment: You don't want to use the `using` block on that Dtable, since that will dispose of it, and you want to use it in your ComboBox.

Comment: @LarsTech yes that was the issue, tanks so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Using` block disposes the data table:

```
using (DataTable Dtable = new DataTable()) {
  SqlDa.Fill(Dtable);
  HiveNumbercmb.DataSource = Dtable;
}
```

so remove that and just declare the variable:

```
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
SqlDa.Fill(dTable);
HiveNumbercmb.DataSource = dTable;
```